# Date format while importing table in sql developer

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to import details from a csv file which i am creating through BI Publisher query from a table.

In the query , I have a date formatted column:

```
effective_start_date

1951-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 
1901-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

Now when i am importing the entire table in excel. How should i import in sql developer in such a way that the date format comes as 'DD-MON-YYYY'

Right now few records for date are getting imprted in table as null !

Also my targer column format is not an editable screen in sql devleoper

Comment: How are you doing in the import - from the data import wizard? Dates don't have intrinsic formats so you're really asking how to convert the string you have into a date. Is the time/time zone part of all the values always "00:00:00.000+00:00"?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole - From Oracle Fusion to csv through BI Publisher.

From csv to table through sql devleoper

Comment: Yes, but exactly what are you doing in SQL Developer? Hmm, the import wizard doesn't like the format you'd need, `YYYY-MM-DD"T00:00:00.000+00:00"`, getting "GDK-05021: date format not recognized", even though the generated insert is valid. Are you able to modify the CSV file creation to export just the YYYY-MM-DD part, if you aren't interested in the time?

Comment: actually while fetching the data only i converted this to to_char(effective_start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy') and then exported

Comment: `CAST( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( value, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM' ) AS DATE )`

Comment: You can't do that in the import wizard though, as far as I can tell, which is why the details of exactly what you are doing are relevant, and why 'fixing' the export part might be necessary. Otherwise you could use a staging table and import as a string, but that's a bit messy too. Or use SQL\*Loader, an external table, etc.

Comment: It is showing invalid: 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM' ) is incorrect i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_LOAD ( id INT, effective_start_date DATE );
```

**CSV**:

```
ID,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
1,1951-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
2,1901-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

**Import (SQL Developer 4.1.0.19)**:

- In the connections panel, right-click on the table name and choose "Import Data..."
- Browse to the csv file then click "Next >".
- Select "Insert Script" as the insert method and click "Next >".
- Click "Next >" to accept the default selected columns.
- In the column definitions, `EFFECTIVE_START_DATE` will have a warning triangle next to it and will say "Data is not compatible with column definition...". Change the format to `YYYY-MM-DD"T00:00:00.000+00:00"` then click "Next >"
- Click "Finish"
- This should bring up a dialog saying "Task successful and sent to worksheet."
- **Optionally**: Do a find/replace on the script replacing `to_date\(('.*?'), '.*?'\)` with `CAST( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( $1, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM' ) AS DATE )` and select the regular expression option and do a "Replace all".
- Run the script (press `F5`).

**Output**

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_LOAD;

ID EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
-- --------------------
 1 1951-01-01 00:00:00
 2 1901-01-01 00:00:00
```

*(The format of the date will depend on your NLS settings.)*